# I got "Unresolved variable" using Svelte with WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, svelte

WebStorm works really bad with Svelte. I'm new in Svelte though may be I didn't miss smth?

I have a store:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
import type { IQuestion } from 'src/utils/db'

interface IQuestionStore {
  activeQuestion: null | IQuestion
  isQuestionShowing: boolean
  isAnswered: boolean
}

const createStore = () => {
  const { subscribe, update } = writable<IQuestionStore>({
    activeQuestion: null,
    isQuestionShowing: false,
    isAnswered: false
  })

  return {
    subscribe,
    answer: () => update((state) => ({ ...state, isAnswered: true })),
    show: (activeQuestion: IQuestion) =>
      update((state) => ({ ...state, activeQuestion, isQuestionShowing: true })),
    close: () =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        update((state) => ({ ...state, isQuestionShowing: false, isAnswered: false }))
      }, 1000)
  }
}

export const questionStore = createStore()
```

And then in component, when I try to get `isAnswered` I get an error in WebStorm "Unresolved variable isAnswered". By the way VSCode doesn't highlight it like an error.

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import { questionStore } from '../store/questionStore'

  console.log($questionStore.isAnswered)
</script>
```

If I convert store to this it works well:

```js
interface IQuestionStore {
  activeQuestion: null | IQuestion
  isQuestionShowing: boolean
  isAnswered: boolean
}

export const questionStore = writable<IQuestionStore>({
    activeQuestion: null,
    isQuestionShowing: false,
    isAnswered: false
  })
```

And! I also have an another store which looks the same in general, just other names. And it works well too! WTF? May be I'm missing something? Or may be I need to make some fixes in WebStorm to force it work well with Svelte?

Comment: Have you came with a solution or any update? I guess restarting svelte language server should help in cases like this.